# Topology of the excluded point topology.

Tags: general-topology

> Fix a set $X$ with at least 2 elements and $p\in X$. Let $\mathcal{T}_p = \{ U \subset X \mid p  \notin U \} \cup \{ X \}$.
>
> 1. Show that $\mathcal{T}_p$ is a topology and denote this topological space by $X$.
> 2. Is $X$ connected?
> 3. Is $X$ Hausdorff?
> 4. Let $(x_n)$ be the sequence with $x_n = a$ for all $n$ for some $a \in X$. For what values of $a$ does $(x_n)$ converge? If $(x_n)$ converges, where does it converge to?

My work.

1. $X, \emptyset \in \mathcal{T}_p$.

   Suppose $U_1 \subset X$ and $U_2 \subset X$ and $p \notin U_1$ and $p \notin U_2$ then $p \notin U_1 \cup U_2 \subset X$ so $U_1 \cup U_2 \in \mathcal{T}_p$ Hence unions of elements of $\mathcal{T}_p$ are in $\mathcal{T}_p$.

   Suppose $U_1 \subset X$ and $U_2 \subset X$ and $p \notin U_1$ and $p \notin U_2$ then $p \notin U_1 \cap U_2 \subset X$ so $U_1 \cap U_2 \in \mathcal{T}_p$ Hence intersections of elements of $\mathcal{T}_p$ are in $\mathcal{T}_p$.
2. $X$ is connected since the only set in $\mathcal{T}_p$ containing $p$ is the entire set $X$, and hence there cannot exist a separation.
3. $X$ is not Hausdorff since it is connected

I think (1) and (2) are right, I think (3) is wrong and I don't know what to do for (4).

Comment: Hausdorff has nothing to see with connectedness. What do you mean with ‘a separation’?

Comment: Proving that *finite* unions of elements of $\mathcal T_p$ belong to $\mathcal T_p$ is not enough.

Comment: The topology is called the ecluded point topology with respect to $p$. Hence the title edit. I also cleaned up the $\LaTeX$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff and connected, for example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is almost correct, but for the union part write it up for arbitrary unions, not just finite ones. Make explicit why $\emptyset \in \mathcal{T}_p$.
2. The reason is essentially correct, make the write-up more formal: suppose $X = A \cup B$ is a separation of $X$. One of the sets contains $p$ etc...
3. This has a bogus argument: the reals are connected and very Hausdorff. Think of the same reason why $X$ is connected (neighbourhoods of $p$) and use that $X$ has another element besides $p$...
4. Just use the definition of convergence. And consider for limits all $x \neq p$ and $p$ separately. What is a typical open neighbourhood of $x \neq p$ and $p$? Does the sequence stay inside the neighbourhood or not?

Comment: Very Hausdorff? Is that a thing? It should be.

Comment: @AsafKaragila a Hausdorff non-regular space should be called barely Hausdorff then as well...

Comment: Sounds like a plan!

Answer (score 1):

An open neighbourhood of a point $x\neq p\in X$ is $X$ or any subset of $X$ which contains $x$, but not $p$. In particular $\{x\}$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$, hence two distinct points $x,y\neq p$ have disjoint neighbourhoods and $X$ would be Hausdorff, except… the only neighbourhood of $p$  is $X$, so that the T<sub>2</sub> axiom (Hausdorff space) is not true for $x$ and $p$.

However, $\mathscr T_p$ satisfies axiom T<sub>0</sub> (Kolmogorov  space): for any points $x\neq y$, there exists a neighbourhood of one of them that doesn't contain the other.